# How to get upload percentage and display it in progress bar

Tags: angular, file-upload

Hello everyone I'm uploading file to backend and I want to get upload percentage and display it in progress bar:

Adding file ts component:

```
   this.updateDokumentSub = this.dokumentiService.insertDokument(obj).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.toastService.showToast('success', 'Novi dokument uspješno dodan', '');
      form.resetForm();
      this.close(true);
      this.dokumentiService.emitAddDokument(obj);
      this.loading = false;
      this.spinner.hide();
    },
      err => {
        console.error(err);
        this.loading = false;
        this.spinner.hide();
      });
```

Service file for uploading:

```
  insertDokument(object: any): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.post(this.apiRoute + '/insertDok', {
    }, object);
  }
```

And here is my progress bar:

```
   <nb-progress-bar [value]="40" status="primary" [displayValue]="true"></nb-progress-bar>
```

Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `XMLHttpRequest` to upload your file.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", 'your file');

const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'your url');
// set authen token if you need
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.auth.token()}`);

request.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
  // process percent via e.lengthComputable, e.loaded, e.total
  progress(e.lengthComputable, e.loaded, e.total);
};
request.onload = () => {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) {
    // process when done
  } else {
    error(request.response);
  }
};
request.send(formData);
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the call you an observable of [HttpEvents](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEvent#description).

```
  insertDokument(dokument: any): Observable<HttpEvent<Object>> {
    return this.http.post<HttpEvent<Object>>(this.apiRoute + '/insertDok', dokument, {
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events',
    });
  }
```

The Observable emits multiple times. HttpEvent can be a [HttpProgressEvent](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpProgressEvent), which contains your required data. Once the upload is done the HttpEvent will change to [HttpResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpResponse).

Every HttpEvent has a `type`attribute, you can use to check which event happened.